# Code for adding Autogenerated ID in Textbox when user clicks on Clear_data button

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created one form in c#, there I need autogenerated ID, which has been displayed automatically when user clicks on *clear data* button. And ID's format should be LEL5-serial No. (serial No. is always in increase case like 1,2,3,..)

Ex: my first record iD is LEL5-1,

My second record id is LEL5-2

Please help.
Thank you.

```
static int EJDS_id = 1;
 string code;

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        EJDS_id = EJDS_id + 1;
        txtjobno.Text = "LEL5-" + EJDS_id.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: have you tried to do anything to achieve that?

Comment: ya i ahave tried but its not working

Comment: what have you tried? post your codes here. Nobody will not create the full solution for you. You have to post your code and then we will help you

Comment: please check above code it will generated autoincremented ID like LEL5-1,LEL5-2,LEL5-3...so on but when table has some records it should be taken last id from my table 1

Comment: Your code is correct only if user will use it in one session. Your static variable on another session will be set again

Comment: can you please help me how can i get the solution.

Comment: do you know how to create database? if yes, I may give you short solution. Otherwise, I have to show also creating an database and all aspects

Comment: Ya i know how to create database,I have use MS access database for my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some table called SERIAL_NUMBERS:

```
create table SERIAL_NUMBERS(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LASTNUMBER INT NOT NULL);
```

Then insert one string to store the last value:

```
insert into SERIAL_NUMBERS(ID, LASTNUMBER) values (1, 0);
```

Then add following namespaces in the code behind:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

Then in your code behind:

```
protected void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UpdateLastNumber();
    txtjobno.Text = "LEL5-" + GetLastNumber().ToString();
}

protected int GetLastNumber(){
    int last = 0;
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringnameFromWebConfigFile"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select lastnumber from serial_numbers where id = 1", con); // I added the condition just to be sure that only one value will be queried
    con.Open();
    last = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    con.Close();
    return last;
}

protected void UpdateLastNumber(){
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringnameFromWebConfigFile"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("update serial_numbers set lastnumber = lastnumber + 1 where id = 1", con); // I added the condition just to be sure that only one value will be queried
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: @shweta You are welcome. But next time you have to do something yourself, and if it does not works, then post here your question with codes, okay? Keep it in mind please.

Comment: @shweta Approve any answer and your question will be "solved".

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "LEL5-1";
int xxxx = Convert.ToInt32(test.Substring(5));
xxxx++;
string result = string.Format("LEL5-{0}", xxxx);
```

Comment: can you please tell me where I need to add this above code

Comment: @shweta go to 'design' part. then double click your 'clear data button'. then you need to change the code also. change 'test' and 'result' with your textbox name. textbox.text

Comment: My Textbox name is textbox1 and its label is E_JDS_ID

Comment: @shweta then you could edit your question, and post what have you done and what code inside your button.

Comment: when I tried to write string in front of my textbox .text ..it gives error . its not allow to write : string then textbox name.